# App reverting to default invariant culture

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server-side app and I'm configuring my cultures in `Startup.cs`

```
var supportedCultures = Configuration.GetSection(MyAppOptions.SectionName)
    .Get<MyAppOptions>().Cultures;
app.UseRequestLocalization(supportedCultures.Select(x => x.Culture).ToArray());
```

I have only 1 culture set and it's `de`.

When I add:

```
@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

In a page or component, the value is correctly set to `de`.

However, when I'm displaying currencies and dates, it's defaulting to `en-US`.

What am I missing?